# How to slice a queue?

Tags: python, python-3.x, queue

I have a queue which I process in a loop

```
while True:
    # a processing loop
    batch = []
    while True:
        e = q.get()
        if e:
            batch.append(e)
        else:
            # the queue is empty
            break
    do_something_with(batch)
    # wait a moment before emptying the queue again
    time.sleep(2)
```

The idea is to empty the queue, process its content and wait a moment before checking the content again.

I sometimes hit a race condition where the queue is alimented while I `get()` an element and I end up with a growing `batch` which is never processed further.

One solution would be to check `batch` size and process it when the size is right. This does not work if I have not that many events getting in the queue and `batch` never reaching the correct size - but I need the events (whatever is their number) to be processed and not wait until enough accumulate.

The second solution is to build a check based on the size and on the time `batch` is idle -- this overly complicates the code.

One good solution would be to *"get up to `n` elements from the queue at once"*. I could not find anything like that in the documentation. **Is there a way to pop several elements at once from the queue (à la slicing for a list)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Queue.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.get) blocks by default; source of infinite loop.

> `Queue.get(block=True, timeout=None)`
>
> Remove and return an item from the queue. **If optional args block is
>   true and timeout is None (the default), block if necessary until an
>   item is available.** If timeout is a positive number, it blocks at most
>   timeout seconds and raises the Empty exception if no item was
>   available within that time. Otherwise (block is false), return an item
>   if one is immediately available, else raise the Empty exception
>   (timeout is ignored in that case).

You should use, [`Queue.get_nowait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.get_nowait) or `Queue.get(block=False)` to prevent block. Or use `Queue.get(timeout=<seconds>)` wait at most `<seconds>` when queue is empty.

Solution mentioned in your question sound good:

```
BATCH_SIZE = 10

while True:
    batch = []

    # Get out of loop if enough item collected or queue is empty
    while len(batch) < BATCH_SIZE:
        try:
            e = q.get_nowait()  # OR q.get(timeout=0.1)
        except Empty:
            break
            # To prevent empty batch
            # if batch:
            #     break

    do_something_with(batch)
    # wait a moment before emptying the queue again
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: I use a similar workaround (I posted it as a solution as well). Your approach will not get me out of the `while` if there are not enough elements, right? Also, `e` is not added to the batch (minior overlooking)

Comment: @WoJ, `get_nowait()` will raise `queue.Empty` exception; it will get you out of the `while` (inner) even though there 's`<BATCH_SIZE` items in `batch`.

Comment: @WoJ, To prevent, empty `batch`, you can replace `break` with `if batch: break`

Comment: @WoJ, Or replace `q.get_nowait()` with `q.get(timeout=0.1)` if you don't want busy loop in case of empty queue.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I am using now, until a better idea/solution:

```
while True:
    # get up to 1000 elements form the queue
    batch = []
    for _ in range(1000):
        try:
            e = q.get(block=False)
        except queue.Empty:
            continue
        else:
            batch.append(e)
    do_something_with(batch)
    time.sleep(2)
```

I may make 1000 useless attempts to get an element (queue empty), or have all of them (even when the queue grows), or anything in between